# Desenvolvimento que mostre diferentes tipos de cálculos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Preciso de ajuda para montar uma página, programa ou aplicação que faça os seguintes tópicos de fundamentos matemáticos e mostre os cálculos que o programa fez.

> - Transposição de Objeto
> - Rotação de Objeto
> - Aumento de Objeto (largura e altura independentes)
> - Espelhamento de Objeto (de ângulos diferentes)
> - Cisalhamento de Objeto (de pontos diferentes)

Fiz uma tela simples que fazem alguns dos movimentos, porém não mostra os calculos e não faz o cisilhamento nem o espelhamento de angulos diferentes.

Juntei os códigos que fiz em um só para ficar mais simples a visualização

```js
    $("#top").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate( {"top": "-=25px"}, "fast");
    });

    $("#bottom").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate( {"top": "+=20px"}, "fast");
    });

    $("#right").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate( 
            {
                "left": "+=15px"
            }, "fast");
    });

    $("#left").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate( {"left": "-=50px"}, "fast");
    });

    $("#aumentar").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate( 
        {
            "height": "+=10px",
            "width": "+=10px"
        }, "fast");
    });

    $("#diminuir").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate( 
            {
                "height": "-=10px",
                "width": "-=10px"
            }, "fast");
    });

    var rotation = 0;

    jQuery.fn.movimento = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    };

    $('#girar').click(function() {
        rotation += 5;
        $(content).movimento(rotation);
    });

    jQuery.fn.movimento2 = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    };

    $('#regirar').click(function() {
        rotation -= 5;
        $(content).movimento2(rotation);
    });



    $("#top2").click(function() {
        $("#content2").animate( {"top": "-=25px"}, "fast");
    });

    $("#bottom2").click(function() {
        $("#content2").animate( {"top": "+=20px"}, "fast");
    });

    $("#right2").click(function() {
        $("#content2").animate( 
            {
                "left": "+=15px"
            }, "fast");
    });

    $("#left2").click(function() {
        $("#content2").animate( {"left": "-=50px"}, "fast");
    });

    $("#aumentar2").click(function() {
        $("#content2").animate( 
        {
            "height": "+=10px",
            "width": "+=10px"
        }, "fast");
    });

    $("#diminuir2").click(function() {
        $("#content2").animate( 
            {
                "height": "-=10px",
                "width": "-=10px"
            }, "fast");
    });

    var rotation = 0;

    jQuery.fn.movimento = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    };

    $('#girar2').click(function() {
        rotation += 5;
        $(content2).movimento(rotation);
    });

    jQuery.fn.movimento2 = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    };

    $('#regirar2').click(function() {
        rotation -= 5;
        $(content2).movimento2(rotation);
    });
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #ededed
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#content {
    background-color: #6688ff;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-indent: -99999;
    left: 100;
    float:left;
    top: 20px;
}

#content2 {
    background-color: #bd0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 3px;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: -9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-indent: -99999;
    float:left;
    top: 60px;
}

.controles{
    border: 0px solid #333;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}

.btn{
    border: 1px solid #6688ff;
    background-color: #6688ff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.btn2{
    border: 1px solid #bd0000;
    background-color: #bd0000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.terreno{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-height: 75%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -99999;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.rotate {
    background: #F02311;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 1em Arial;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controles">
            <input type="button" id="left" value="Esquerda" class="btn">
            <input type="button" id="right" value="Direita" class="btn">
            <input type="button" id="bottom" value="Baixo" class="btn">
            <input type="button" id="top" value="Topo" class="btn">
        </div>

        <div class="controles">
            <input type="button" id="aumentar" value="Aumentar" class="btn">
            <input type="button" id="diminuir" value="Diminuir" class="btn">
            <input type="button" id="girar" value="Girar Esquerda" class="btn">
            <input type="button" id="regirar" value="Girar Direita" class="btn">
        </div>

        <div class="controles">
            <input type="button" id="left2" value="Esquerda" class="btn2">
            <input type="button" id="bottom2" value="Baixo" class="btn2">
            <input type="button" id="top2" value="Topo" class="btn2">
            <input type="button" id="right2" value="Direita" class="btn2">
        <div>

        <div class="controles">
            <input type="button" id="aumentar2" value="Aumentar" class="btn2">
            <input type="button" id="diminuir2" value="Diminuir" class="btn2">
            <input type="button" id="girar2" value="Girar Esquerda" class="btn2">
            <input type="button" id="regirar2" value="Girar Direita" class="btn2">
        </div>

        <div class="terreno">
            <div id="content">Objeto 1</div>
            <div id="content2" class="content2" >Objeto 2</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla, e poderá ser fechada. Aconselho a separar esses tópicos em perguntas distintas, explicando o objetivo esperado e apresentando o que já possuí. Desta forma será mais fácil entender cada tópico, extraindo respostas melhores para cada um. Só lembrando, alguns destes tópicos podem ter perguntas parecidas.

Comment: Consegui desenvolver, existe alguma forma de partilhar algum ZIP no StackOverflow?

Comment: você pode colocar o código em https://jsfiddle.net e depois postar o link aqui como comentário

Comment: @WilsonRosaGomes não precisa usar o jsfiddle.net aqui mesmo tem uma opção para 'Trecho Javascript/HTML/CSS' e opções de bibliotecas externas